# Can't connect to xrdp ubuntu

Tags: xrdp

I installed xrdp and xfce4 on my ubuntu 22.04 server to connect using mstsc.exe on windows, but i can not. Xrdp is working and i added rule in iptables on 3389 port. But mstsc.exe tells me "failed to connect to remote desktop". I tryed a lot of ways to fix it, but could not

Comment: Hello there... Not enough information provided here.  The error message tells already that the remote machine is not accessible or that some of the xrdp services are not running.  How did you performed the installation of xRDP ?